# Remove lines where next line matches certain pattern

Tags: bash

I have a following simple script for parsing out dates from irc logs (created by irssi)

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                  
query=$1

grep -n $query logfile > matches.log 
grep -n "Day changed" logfile >> matches.log

cat matches.log | sort -n
```

It produces output like:

```
--- Day changed Tue Jul 03 2012
--- Day changed Wed Jul 04 2012
--- Day changed Thu Jul 05 2012
16:54 <@Hamatti> who let the dogs out
--- Day changed Fri Jul 06 2012
--- Day changed Sat Jul 07 2012
--- Day changed Sun Jul 08 2012
12:11 <@Hamatti> dogs are fun
```

But since I'm only interested in finding out dates for actual matches, I'd like to filter out all those

```
--- Day changed XXX XXX dd dddd
```

lines where they don't follow by timestamp on the next line. So the example should output

```
--- Day changed Thu Jul 05 2012
16:54 <@Hamatti> who let the dogs out
--- Day changed Sun Jul 08 2012
12:11 <@Hamatti> dogs are fun
```

to get rid of all the disinformation that's not useful.

edit.
After the answer by T. Zelieke I realised that I could make this more of a one-liner so I use the following now to save logfile from being iterated twice.

```
query=$1
egrep "$query|Day changed" logfile |grep -B1 "^[^-]" |sed '/^--$/d'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -B1 "^[^-]" data |sed '/^--$/d'
```

This uses `grep` to filter lines that do NOT start with a dash (`"^[^-]"`). `-B1` asks to print the immediate line before a match.
Unfortunately `grep` separates then each match (pair of two lines) by an `--` line. Therefore I pipe the output through `sed` to get rid of those superflouos lines.

Comment: Thanks, this on does the charm. For educational purposes, could you open up it a bit, why does it work?

edit. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using awk.

```
awk -v query="$1" '/^--- Day changed/{day=$0;next} $0 ~ query {if (day!=p) {print day;p=day}; print}'
```

Every time it finds a "Day changed" line, it stores it in the variable `day`. Then when it finds a match to the query, it outputs the currently stored day line first. In case there are multiple matches in the same day, the variable `p` is used to determine if the day-line has been printed already.